# How to access GCP bucket label without bucket name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

How do I get the bucket labels of all the buckets in a project.

gsutil label get gs:// url

This command needs the bucket url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
PROJECT=... # Your Project ID

BUCKETS=$(gsutil ls -p ${PROJECT})

for BUCKET in ${BUCKETS}
do
  gsutil label get ${BUCKET}
done
```